# center using margin:auto for an img in a paragraph is not working

Tags: css

I am trying to center an image inside a `<p>`
I used this website, http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html, and also found similar examples here but nothing seems to work.

My HTML code is

```
<div class="span4">
     <h3 class="aglow" id="h3Body">Forms</h3>
     <p>
        <a class="btn btn-link "href="teacher_forms_list.html">
           <img class="operationsButtons" src="NewForms.png" alt="forms">
        </a>
     </p>
</div>
```

and my CSS

```
   img.operationsButtons {
       display: block;
       margin-left: auto;
       margin-right: auto;    
   }
```

but for some reason the image is still on the left (attaching a picture of the image and a h3 that is centered over it)

[image: Not centered]

thank you for your help

Comment: Try to close img tag: http://jsfiddle.net/cabwu/2/

Comment: If you are using margin auto, you need to define a fix width to that element

Comment: @Mr. Alien look at my fiddle. There is no need to set fixed width. It should align to current parent width (or parent's parent).

Comment: @Alex He needs the image to be centered

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dolours/xyZDp/1/ whats pbm with your code

Comment: @Mr. Alien you say that image in my fiddle aligned to left? http://jsfiddle.net/cabwu/4/. His code works well, so maybe the problem is outside of that code block.

Comment: @Alex You can refer to my answer

Comment: If the problem *is* elsewhere, I'd start by checking the styles of `a`, `.btn`, `.btn-link`, and/or maybe `a img` to make sure they're not set to be displayed as inline-blocks. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tamil Selvan answred, you can simply use `text-align: center;` - [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/b9rCf/)

If you are using `margin: auto;` than you need to define width for your `img` element as well as `display: block;` as `img` is an inline element by default  - [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/q3MYH/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put

```
p
{
text-align: center;
}
```